# Why is a || go(x) a tail call ins call and 1 + go(x) is not?

Tags: scala, recursion, tail-recursion

I am learning Scala with the use of [Functional Programming in Scala](https://www.manning.com/books/functional-programming-in-scala) book. Its Github companion notes say that `a || go(x)` is still a tail call-optimised recursion while `1 + go(x)` is not. How is that computation different and why can compiler optimise one but not the other?

Comment: `1 + go(x)` needs to evaluate `go(x)` before retuning the sum, whereas `a || go(x)` already evaluated `a` and if it was `false` then it evaluates `go(x)`  and it doesn't need its result to do any other extra work after.

Comment: For tail recursion, the final operation must be the recursive call. In `1 + go(x)` the final operation is the addition. On the other hand, the `||` operator is lazy: if 'a' is true it just evaluates to true; only if `a` is false does it evaluate `go(x)`, so `go(x)` is the final operation => tail recursive.

Comment: Irritatingly, these two comments are great answers, but the only actual answer is very poor. Why do neither of you want to put your comments in an answer?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To explain it more succinctly: for tail recursion, the final operation must be the recursive call.

In `1 + go(x)` the final operation is the addition.

On the other hand, the `||` operator is lazy: if `a` is true the expression `a || go(x)` just evaluates to true; only if `a` is false is `go(x)` evaluated, so `go(x)` is the final operation, thus it's tail recursive.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have following method.

```scala
def sumOfN(n: Int): Int = 
  if (n <= 0)
    0
  else
    n + sumOfN(n - 1)
```

Now, this function is not tail recursive. Why ? Lets look at logical execution of sumOfN(3).

While executing this, the stack will look like,

```
sumOfN(3)
```

```
3 + sumOfN(2)
```

```
sumOfN(2)
3 + sumOfN(2)
```

```
2 + sumOfN(1)
3 + sumOfN(2)
```

```
sumOfN(1)
2 + sumOfN(1)
3 + sumOfN(2)
```

```
1 + sumOfN(0)
2 + sumOfN(1)
3 + sumOfN(2)
```

```
sumOfN(0)
1 + sumOfN(0)
2 + sumOfN(1)
3 + sumOfN(2)
```

```
0
1 + sumOfN(0)
2 + sumOfN(1)
3 + sumOfN(2)
```

```
1 + 0
2 + sumOfN(1)
3 + sumOfN(2)
```

```
1
2 + sumOfN(1)
3 + sumOfN(2)
```

```
2 + 1
3 + sumOfN(2)
```

```
3
3 + sumOfN(2)
```

```
3 + 3
```

```
6
```

Any, recursive method which grows on stack is NOT tail recursive.

But, if we look at the case of that boolean method

```scala
def isZeroSomewhere(n: Int): Boolean = 
  (n == 0) ||  isZeroSomewhere(n - 1)
```

This will be tail recursive due to branch optimizations for `boolean OR`. This roughly means that two branches of the stack will be created, the branch with `isZeroSomewhere(n - 1)` will be evaluated only if `(n == 0)` is `not true` (`(n == 0)` banch will be terminated).

```
isZeroSomewhere(3)
```

```
// branch 1              // branch2
(3 == 0)                 isZeroSomewhere(2)
// false,terminate       // needs further evaluation
```

```
isZeroSomewhere(2)
```

```
// branch 1              // branch2
(2 == 0)                 isZeroSomewhere(1)
// false,terminate       // needs further evaluation
```

```
isZeroSomewhere(1)
```

```
// branch 1              // branch2
(1 == 0)                 isZeroSomewhere(0)
// false,terminate       // needs further evaluation
```

```
isZeroSomewhere(0)
```

```
// branch 1              // branch2
(0 == 0)                 isZeroSomewhere(-1)
// true                  // the other branch is true, terminate
```

As, you can see the stack size in this case is not growing at all. So, this is tail recursive.

Keep in mind that this branch optimization is done from left to right. So, this following method is NOT tail recursive. It's actually an infinite loop in left branch and will always cause stack overflow.

```
def isZeroSomewhere(n: Int): Boolean =
  isZeroSomewhere(n - 1) || (n == 0)
```